# "There has been an error processing your request" after clicking manage categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category, configuration, theme

I am getting this error when I click on manage categories in admin and when i checked the var/report, I got this. I have already deleted my previous theme "eclipse" but i think it's still messing up with the database. Need help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the database in `eav_attribute` table search this string `ecliplsesettings/category_attribute_source_menutype` u will find this in that column remove this and then clear cache and try again

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing a file or you had an extension that you disabled.
Does the name `eclipsesettings` ring a bell?
If it does and the extension is still active you should contact the developer.
If you removed the extension, you need to remove the attribute that the extension added.

Look in the table `eav_attribute` for a record with `source_model = 'ecliplsesettings/category_attribute_source_menutype'` and remove the record.
Then clear the cache and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. However, I found the record of my previous themes also in the database, Can I also delete them ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the record of my previous themes also in the database".

Comment: In the table, "eav_attribute" , there are strings of my previous themes also that i don't use now.

Comment: sure, you can delete them, but make sure you backup your db before doing that. You might delete something you need.